# C++ 20 ranges custom sortable container error : candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with _Range = ...] operator()(..) const

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, std-ranges

I wrote a simple class template wrapping around a raw array just to play with the C++ 20 ranges library and wanted it to support random access iterators and make it work with std::ranges::sort.

```
#ifndef BOX_CONTAINER_H
#define BOX_CONTAINER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T> requires  std::is_default_constructible_v<T>
class BoxContainer
{
    static const size_t DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 5;  
    static const size_t EXPAND_STEPS = 5;
public:
    BoxContainer(size_t capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    BoxContainer(const BoxContainer<T>& source);
    ~BoxContainer();
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const BoxContainer<T>& operand)
    {
        out << "BoxContainer : [ size :  " << operand.m_size
            << ", capacity : " << operand.m_capacity << ", items : " ;
                
        for(size_t i{0}; i < operand.m_size; ++i){
            out << operand.m_items[i] << " " ;
        }
        out << "]";
        
        return out;
    }
    
    // Helper getter methods
    size_t size( ) const { return m_size; }
    size_t capacity() const{return m_capacity;};
    
    T get_item(size_t index) const{
        return m_items[index];
    }
    
    //Method to add items to the box
    void add(const T& item);
    bool remove_item(const T& item);
    size_t remove_all(const T& item);
    //In class operators
    void operator +=(const BoxContainer<T>& operand);
    void operator =(const BoxContainer<T>& source);

public : 
    class Iterator 
    {
    public : 
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type        = T;
        using pointer_type           = T*;
        using reference_type         = T&;

        Iterator() = default;
        Iterator(pointer_type ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}
    
        reference_type operator*() const {
            return *m_ptr;
        }
        pointer_type operator->() {
            return m_ptr;
        }
        Iterator& operator++() {
            m_ptr++; return *this;
        }  
        Iterator operator++(int) {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        
        //Random access
        Iterator& operator--() {
            m_ptr--; return *this;
        }  
        Iterator operator--(int) {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            --(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        
        
        Iterator& operator+=(const difference_type offset) {
            m_ptr += offset;
            return *this;
        }

       Iterator operator+(const difference_type offset) const  {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            return tmp += offset;
        }
        
        Iterator& operator-=(const difference_type offset) {
            return *this += -offset;
        }

        Iterator operator-(const difference_type offset) const  {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            return tmp -= offset;
        }

        difference_type operator-(const Iterator& right) const {
            return m_ptr - right.m_ptr;
        }
        
        reference_type operator[](const difference_type offset) const  {
            return *(*this + offset);
        }
        
        bool operator<(const Iterator& right) const  {
            return m_ptr < right.m_ptr;
        }

        bool operator>(const Iterator& right) const  {
            return right < *this;
        }

        bool operator<=(const Iterator& right) const {
            return !(right < *this);
        }

        bool operator>=(const Iterator& right) const  {
            return !(*this < right);
        }


        //These operators are non members, but can still access private
        //members of Iterator. Cool.
        friend bool operator== (const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) {
            return a.m_ptr == b.m_ptr;
        };
        friend bool operator!= (const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) {
            return a.m_ptr != b.m_ptr; 
        };  
    
    private:
        pointer_type m_ptr;
    };
    
    Iterator begin() { return Iterator(&m_items[0]); }
    Iterator end()   { return Iterator(&m_items[m_size]); }
private : 
    void expand(size_t new_capacity);   
private : 
    T * m_items;
    size_t m_capacity;
    size_t m_size;
    
};

//Free operators
template <typename T> requires  std::is_default_constructible_v<T>
BoxContainer<T> operator +(const BoxContainer<T>& left, const BoxContainer<T>& right);

template <typename T> requires  std::is_default_constructible_v<T>
BoxContainer<T>::BoxContainer(size_t capacity)
{
    m_items = new T[capacity];
    m_capacity = capacity;
    m_size =0;
}

template <typename T> requires  std::is_default_constructible_v<T>
BoxContainer<T>::BoxContainer(const BoxContainer<T>& source)
{
    //Set up the new box
    m_items = new T[source.m_capacity];
    m_capacity = source.m_capacity;
    m_size = source.m_size;
    
    //Copy the items over from source 
    for(size_t i{} ; i < source.size(); ++i){
        m_items[i] = source.m_items[i];
    }
}

template <typename T> requires std::is_default_constructible_v<T>
BoxContainer<T>::~BoxContainer()
{
    delete[] m_items;
}

template <typename T> requires std::is_default_constructible_v<T>
void BoxContainer<T>::expand(size_t new_capacity){
    std::cout << "Expanding to " << new_capacity << std::endl;
    T *new_items_container;

    if (new_capacity <= m_capacity)
        return; // The needed capacity is already there
    
    //Allocate new(larger) memory
    new_items_container = new T[new_capacity];

    //Copy the items over from old array to new 
    for(size_t i{} ; i < m_size; ++i){
        new_items_container[i] = m_items[i];
    }
    
    //Release the old array
    delete [ ] m_items;
    
    //Make the current box wrap around the new array
    m_items = new_items_container;
    
    //Use the new capacity
    m_capacity = new_capacity;
}

template <typename T> requires  std::is_default_constructible_v<T>
void BoxContainer<T>::add(const T& item){
    if (m_size == m_capacity)
        //expand(m_size+5); // Let's expand in increments of 5 to optimize on the calls to expand
        expand(m_size + EXPAND_STEPS);
    m_items[m_size] = item;
    ++m_size;
}

template <typename T> requires std::is_default_constructible_v<T>
bool BoxContainer<T>::remove_item(const T& item){
    
    //Find the target item
    size_t index {m_capacity + 999}; // A large value outside the range of the current 
                                        // array
    for(size_t i{0}; i < m_size ; ++i){
        if (m_items[i] == item){
            index = i;
            break; // No need for the loop to go on
        }
    }
    
    if(index > m_size)
        return false; // Item not found in our box here
        
    //If we fall here, the item is located at m_items[index]
    
    //Overshadow item at index with last element and decrement m_size
    m_items[index] = m_items[m_size-1];
    m_size--;
    return true;
}

//Removing all is just removing one item, several times, until
//none is left, keeping track of the removed items.
template <typename T> requires std::is_default_constructible_v<T>
size_t BoxContainer<T>::remove_all(const T& item){
    
    size_t remove_count{};
    
    bool removed = remove_item(item);
    if(removed)
        ++remove_count;
    
    while(removed == true){
        removed = remove_item(item);
        if(removed)
            ++ remove_count;
    }
    
    return remove_count;
}

template <typename T> requires std::is_default_constructible_v<T>
void BoxContainer<T>::operator +=(const BoxContainer<T>& operand){
    
    //Make sure the current box can acommodate for the added new elements
    if( (m_size + operand.size()) > m_capacity)
        expand(m_size + operand.size());
        
    //Copy over the elements
    for(size_t i{} ; i < operand.m_size; ++i){
        m_items [m_size + i] = operand.m_items[i];
    }
    
    m_size += operand.m_size;
}

template <typename T> requires std::is_default_constructible_v<T>
BoxContainer<T> operator +(const BoxContainer<T>& left, const BoxContainer<T>& right){
    BoxContainer<T> result(left.size( ) + right.size( ));
    result += left; 
    result += right;
    return result;  
}

template <typename T> requires std::is_default_constructible_v<T>
void BoxContainer<T>::operator =(const BoxContainer<T>& source){
    T *new_items;

    // Check for self-assignment:
    if (this == &source)
            return;

    // If the capacities are different, set up a new internal array
    //that matches source, because we want object we are assigning to 
    //to match source as much as possible.

    if (m_capacity != source.m_capacity)
    { 
        new_items = new T[source.m_capacity];
        delete [ ] m_items;
        m_items = new_items;
        m_capacity = source.m_capacity;
    }
    
    //Copy the items over from source 
    for(size_t i{} ; i < source.size(); ++i){
        m_items[i] = source.m_items[i];
    }
    
    m_size = source.m_size;
}

#endif // BOX_CONTAINER_H
```

I try it out just like below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include "boxcontainer.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    BoxContainer<int> box1;
    box1.add(8);
    box1.add(1);
    box1.add(4);
    box1.add(2);
    box1.add(5);
    box1.add(3);
    box1.add(7);
    box1.add(9);
    box1.add(6);

    std::cout << "box1 : " << box1 << std::endl;
    std::ranges::sort(box1); // FAILS
    
   // std::cout << "box1 : " << box1 << std::endl;
    
    //std::ranges::reverse(box1); // Works
    
    std::cout << "box1 : " << box1 << std::endl;
   
    return 0;
}
```

And get failed concept constraints I can't make sense of as of now. The detailed compiler output is below

```
clang++.exe -g -std=c++20 E:\Sandbox\FuntionTemplatesRevisit\03.RandomAccessIteratorStrippedDown\*.cpp -o E:\Sandbox\FuntionTemplatesRevisit\03.RandomAccessIteratorStrippedDown\rooster.exe
E:\Sandbox\FuntionTemplatesRevisit\03.RandomAccessIteratorStrippedDown\main.cpp:40:5: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const std::ranges::__sort_fn'
    std::ranges::sort(box1); // 
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits/ranges_algo.h:2038:7: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with _Range = BoxContainer<int> &, _Comp = std::ranges::less, _Proj = std::identity]
      operator()(_Range&& __r, _Comp __comp = {}, _Proj __proj = {}) const
      ^
C:\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits/ranges_algo.h:2034:14: note: because 'BoxContainer<int> &' does not satisfy 'random_access_range'
    template<random_access_range _Range,
             ^
C:\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits/ranges_base.h:649:37: note: because 'iterator_t<BoxContainer<int> &>' (aka 'BoxContainer<int>::Iterator') does not satisfy 'random_access_iterator'
      = bidirectional_range<_Tp> && random_access_iterator<iterator_t<_Tp>>;
                                    ^
C:\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits/iterator_concepts.h:669:8: note: because '__n + __j' would be invalid: invalid operands to binary expression ('const iter_difference_t<BoxContainer<int>::Iterator>' (aka 'const long long') and 'const BoxContainer<int>::Iterator')
        { __n +  __j } -> same_as<_Iter>;
              ^
C:\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits/ranges_algo.h:2025:7: note: candidate function template not viable: requires at least 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
      operator()(_Iter __first, _Sent __last,
      ^
1 error generated.
```

The class is being sorted without a problem for the non range sort algorithm but I don't know what I am missing to make this work with std::ranges::sort. May be something missing in my iterator class? Would appreciate an input on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out. Turns out the compiler was really helpful in telling me what's wrong. The key is this part in the error message :

```
because '__n + __j' would be invalid: invalid operands to binary expression ('const iter_difference_t<BoxContainer<int>::Iterator>' (aka 'const long long') and 'const BoxContainer<int>::Iterator')
        { __n +  __j } -> same_as<_Iter>;
```

My iterators were missing an operator+ that takes an offset as the first parameter and an iterator as the second parameter.

Adding that operator :

```
        friend Iterator operator+(const difference_type offset, const Iterator& it){
            Iterator tmp = it;
            return tmp += offset;
        }
```

Fixes the problem and my sort algorithm is working as expected. Another helpful thing with C++ 20 concepts is that you can do a compile time check to see if your container satisfies a given range concept requirement. Something like

```
static_assert(std::ranges::random_access_range<BoxContainer<int>>);
```

Will tell you if your container has the needed requirement. Hoping this helps someone else in the future.